# How to run kotlin script in the scripting host of Android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-script

I want to run kotlin script(in string form) within Android:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val engine = KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine()
        engine.eval("val x =3")
        val result = engine.eval("x+2")
        Log.d("test", "onCreate: result=$result")
    }
}
```

the dependency i added:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:1.4.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.4.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.0"
```

But i cant compile the code,the error is "Duplicate class" :

```
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.WallTotalProfiler found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.4.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.4.0) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.4.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.4.0)
```

If i remove the dependency of kotlin-compiler-embeddable, Duplicate class error is gone.But a new error occur:

```
Cannot access 'javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.script.experimental.jsr223.KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

As the error is saying, you have duplicated classes in your modules. It means a class is included in two or more of your added dependencies. You should check the dependencies of these modules and use `exclude` to exclude duplicated dependencies from them so that only one of your dependencies contains that duplicated dependency.

You can read more about Gradle's exclude [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api.artifacts/-module-dependency/exclude.html).

 Also, you can use Gradle's [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html) command to generate a tree of all of your project's dependencies.

Note that there are other ways to resolve this problem, Just search for 'Removing duplicated classes in gradle modules' or something like this :)